# Can we get siblings in Jannah if we don't have them in this world?

Tags: jannah

If someone does not have an elder sister or brother in this world, but he or she always wanted one, so will it be possible in Jannah?

Comment: You will get whatever you desire in Jannah. So the answer, in short, is yes

Comment: Allah  knows best because what you desire involves not only your wish but the agreement of your parents (for it be to technically your sibling) ... what if you say yes but they say no ... also I'm not even if sure if the concept exists in Jannah as it involves najas. Remember while the dwellers of Jannah will eat & drink, they won't excrete like on earth. Instead, their sweat which will smell as sweet as musk will do that function ...how? Allah Knows Best.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really possible to understand what Jannat is like. But given that in the Islamic umma we are encouraged to think of all Muslim men as our brothers, and all Muslim women as our sisters then it's possible in Jannat that you will find that you have many brothers and sisters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,It Is Possible As You Can Get Anything You wish in Jannah.As In Jannah There Is Everything What Souls wish and desire.